# Overflow with div height 100% looks different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, overflow

Someone can explain why, in the following example, Chrome shows the scroll within the 2nd row (that's what I expected) and Firefox shows it outside the table.
In other words, why does not Firefox limit the height of the second row?
How would I do it to work in Firefox as well as in Chrome?
Thanks!

```html
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <h1 id="titol">HELLO</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 100%;">
        <td style="border: 1px solid black;">
            <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: auto;">
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You may be looking at different error handling for `<tr style="height...`. Since tr elements aren't supposed to have heights, the browsers may differ in how they treat this. Also, `height:100%` means the height of the parent; but the height of, in this example, the body, is not set explicitly.

Comment: I tried putting <body style = "100%"> but it has not worked either. I guess that's what you say about the height of <tr>.
I finally got it but I had to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it WITHOUT javascript!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Hello
        </title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            #container {
                height: 100%;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            #header {
                flex-grow: 0;
            }

            #content {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                height: 100%;
                overflow-y: auto;
                flex-grow: 1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
                <h1>HELLO</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                FirstHello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
                Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>LastHello
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body onresize="setContentHeight()" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: hidden;">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: auto;">
        FirstHello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>
        Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>LastHello
    </div>
</body>
<script>
function setContentHeight() {
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = document.body.clientHeight - document.getElementById("content").offsetTop;
}
setContentHeight();
</script>
</html>
```